# Xtify Datastore Richnotification db is Nil

Tags: database, null, datastore, iphone-5, xtify

I must say I've been seeing that your support team is terrific, batting many, many problems successfully.  Kudos on heroic support.

Here's my little one.

I installed everything by the book, and ran the code on my iPhone 5, firmware 6.0.1.  It's giving the following error:  ERROR Creating data store. Datastore for richnotification db is nil.  Below is the log.  Also below is the last exception backtrace.

```
-[XLappMgr registerForPush] [Line 325]  Attempt to register for push notifications...
Reachability Flag Status: WR t------ networkStatusForFlags
Succeeded registering for push notifications. Device token: <left out for security purposes, but valid.>
ERROR Creating data store. Datastore for richnotification db is nil


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation      0x3972a3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib     0x385b695e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation      0x3972a302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
3   Foundation          0x39964f14 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 72
4   Foundation          0x39964e3e +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 38
5   Rabbit              0x00108acc -[XLDbMgr managedObjectModel]     (XLDbMgr.m:74)
6   Rabbit              0x00108caa -[XLDbMgr createNewDatabase] (XLDbMgr.m:101)
7   Rabbit              0x00108b4c -[XLDbMgr persistentStoreCoordinator] (XLDbMgr.m:89)
8   Rabbit              0x001088f0 -[XLDbMgr managedObjectContext] (XLDbMgr.m:47)
9   Rabbit              0x0010883c +[XLDbMgr getDBMgr] (XLDbMgr.m:23)
10  Rabbit              0x000fba10 -[AppDetailsMgr init] (AppDetailsMgr.m:33)
11  Rabbit              0x000fb97c +[AppDetailsMgr get] (AppDetailsMgr.m:26)
12  Rabbit              0x00110fd2 -[XLServerMgr sendProviderDeviceToken] (XLServerMgr.m:94)
13  Rabbit              0x00110d0c -[XLServerMgr initWithReg:] (XLServerMgr.m:64)
14  Rabbit              0x001000d6 -[XLappMgr registerWithXtify:] (XLappMgr.m:118)
15  Rabbit              0x0008073e -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] (AppDelegate.m:54)
16  UIKit               0x38c5f7ee _UIXXRemoteNotificationRegistrationSucceeded + 146
17  UIKit               0x38c60278 _XRemoteNotificationRegistrationSucceeded + 112
18  AppSupport          0x36a9940c migHelperRecievePortCallout + 188
19  CoreFoundation      0x396ff3e2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
20  CoreFoundation      0x396ff386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
21  CoreFoundation      0x396fe20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
22  CoreFoundation      0x39671238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23  CoreFoundation      0x396710c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24  GraphicsServices    0x369aa336 GSEventRunModal + 70
25  UIKit               0x38a6128c UIApplicationMain + 1116
26  Rabbit              0x0008055a main (main.m:16)
27  Rabbit              0x000804fc start + 36
```

Comment: Hi Ron, are you getting this error when you build the sample app or is this within your own app?

Comment: Within my own app, Michael.

Comment: But I recently reset my push certificate on the server, because it was previously used somewhere else.  Another company that didn't provide any support.

Comment: Would you please try building the sample app included in the SDK to see if you experience the same result?  It sounds as if there is a conflict somewhere. I will ask my team mates regarding this error.

Answer (score 2):

I did ANE for Adobe AIR App and I had to solve this problem for a long time, but finally I realized the reason: **The resource files that are in the XtifyLib / XtifyPush.embeddedframework / XtifyPush.framework / Versions / A / Resources / must always be added to the project** in my case, with ANE it should be in the folder iPhone-ARM, because ADT moves them to the top-level directory - it is there where it is necessary